# Map a value to a boolean at indexing time in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I get JSON object with a string field that has 2 values of "yes" or "no".

Is it possible to define a mapping that maps "yes" to "true" and "no" to "false"?

What if the values are not yes/no but two other strings, such as "yep" and "nope"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes for the use case in OP, from [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#boolean) :

> The boolean type also supports passing the value as a number or a
>   string (in this case 0, an empty string, false, off and **no** are false,
>   all other values are true).

So "**no**" would map to false and "**yes**" would map to true , just need to specify the field to be of type "boolean" in the mapping.

Comment: Thanks!
What if it was a "yep" and "nope" though? Can I map any two values? Any one value vs all others?

Comment: explicit mapping for boolean values is not supported